# How do I combine ANTLR lexer rules from different lexer grammars?

Tags: antlr, dsl, lexer

I am playing around with ANTLR and building a DSL like jsx.

But in jsx you have javasciprt expressions inside {}, how can I define those ECMAScript rules in my lexer grammar? Should I rewrite the whole ECMAScript lexer from scratch or there are some ways to import those rules in my lexer grammar?

```
<div class={javasciprt expression in here}></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [lexical modes](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexer-rules.md#lexical-modes) for that:

```
lexer grammar YourCurrentLexer;

EXISTING_TOKEN
 : '...' 
 ;

// other tokens

ECMA_START
 : '{' -> pushMode(ECMA_MODE)
 ;

mode ECMA_MODE;

 ECMA_TOKEN
  : '...'
  ;

 // other ECMA tokens
 
 // Support nested { ... }
 OPEN_BRACE
  : '{' -> pushMode(ECMA_MODE)
  ;

 CLOSE_BRACE
  : '}' -> popMode
  ;
```

> Should I rewrite the whole ECMAScript lexer from scratch or there are some ways to import those rules in my lexer grammar?

You cannot just import an existing grammar inside a lexical mode. Just copy-paste the rules you want: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/javascript/ecmascript/JavaScript/ECMAScript.g4